# Problem with HTML/CSS/JS Form. Not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, forms

Here is my code:
https://codepen.io/raakh/pen/wvRqRGX

```js
'use strict';

$(function() {
    $("input[type='password'][data-eye]").each(function(i) {
        var $this = $(this),
            id = 'eye-password-' + i,
            el = $('#' + id);

        $this.wrap($("<div/>", {
            style: 'position:relative',
            id: id
        }));

        $this.css({
            paddingRight: 60
        });
        $this.after($("<div/>", {
            html: 'Show',
            class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm',
            id: 'passeye-toggle-'+i,
        }).css({
                position: 'absolute',
                right: 10,
                top: ($this.outerHeight() / 2) - 12,
                padding: '2px 7px',
                fontSize: 12,
                cursor: 'pointer',
        }));

        $this.after($("<input/>", {
            type: 'hidden',
            id: 'passeye-' + i
        }));

        var invalid_feedback = $this.parent().parent().find('.invalid-feedback');

        if(invalid_feedback.length) {
            $this.after(invalid_feedback.clone());
        }

        $this.on("keyup paste", function() {
            $("#passeye-"+i).val($(this).val());
        });
        $("#passeye-toggle-"+i).on("click", function() {
            if($this.hasClass("show")) {
                $this.attr('type', 'password');
                $this.removeClass("show");
                $(this).removeClass("btn-outline-primary");
            }else{
                $this.attr('type', 'text');
                $this.val($("#passeye-"+i).val());              
                $this.addClass("show");
                $(this).addClass("btn-outline-primary");
            }
        });
    });

    $(".my-login-validation").submit(function() {
        var form = $(this);
        if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.addClass('was-validated');
    });
});



var form = document.querySelector('.needs-validation');
if(form){
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
})
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
    <main role="main" class="container">
<form method="POST" action="/adminLogin"
    class="form-width form-horizontal main-form needs-validation"
    novalidate>
    <h3 class="form-title">Login</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <div class="input-group" id="idEmail">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" value=""
                id="email" required
                pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
                oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Email format is not correct or is not in English Language')"
                ;
                        onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Email format is not correct or is
                not in English Language</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <div class="input-group" id="">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" value=""
                id="password" required
                oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Password format is not correct or is not in English Language')"
                ;
                        onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"> <a href="#"
                    class="toggle_hide_password"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i></a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Password format is not correct or
                is not in English Language</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="from" value=""> <input type="hidden"
        name="userType" value="1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
</form>
<br><br>
```

The main problem is with detecting email format. I am not understanding either problem is with html/css/js or regex. Please help me to fix this issue

`email@email.com` working fine. `email@email.` is also works but the `email@email` is considered correct format instead of wrong format

Please help me to find out error

Best Regards

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Comment: Where is your code? If you use `<input type="email">` it won't accept `email@email`

Comment: @Barmar I believe it will as you can see here https://codepen.io/cornonthecob/pen/dywzwYN. I think it is technically correct syntax (even though it's not allowed in practice)

Comment: Please read up on [how to create an MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and then edit your question to follow those guidelines. In particular, the code needs to be as text within your question (not a link) and must be the minimal amount of code necessary to demo the issue.

Comment: @cornonthecob True, there's nothing prohibiting a TLD from operating a mail server, so `user@com` is valid.

Comment: There's no `setCustomVisibility()` function in your JavaScript. You're not seeing the error from calling that undefined function because of the `try/catch` you have around it.

Comment: @Barmar so how can I restrict it to check complete email format like `user@mail.com`. I mean all 4 parts of email like `user` + `@` + `mail` + `dot` + `tld`?

Comment: Your regexp seems to work, see https://regex101.com/r/CJhpFv/1.

Comment: why use a `pattern` since the `type="email"` already carries out a check on email addresses ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape some of the characters in the pattern, like `[\/\{\|\}\-]+` (so, here just the escaped chars). Remove the `novalidate` attribute from the form element and then use the build in validation.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if(e.target.validity.valid){
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});
```

```css
input.invalid ~ div.invalid-feedback {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
  <main role="main" class="container">
    <form method="POST" name="form01" action="/adminLogin" class="form-width form-horizontal main-form needs-validation">
      <h3 class="form-title">Login</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
          </div>
          <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" pattern="^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`\{\|\}~\-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`\{\|\}~\-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9])?$" data-message="Email format is not correct or is not in English Language" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Email format is not correct or is not in English Language</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" required data-message="Password format is not correct or is not in English Language">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text"><a href="#" class="toggle_hide_password"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i></a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Password format is not correct or is not in English Language</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="from" value=""> <input type="hidden" name="userType" value="1">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
    </form>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: this fixing the email problem but removed all other formatting that is used previously

Comment: @LifeSaver yes, I coudn't figure out what that code did, so I just sticked to the question asked; how to fix the validation. But as I see it it must be possible to use CSS to do whatever the left out code does.

Answer (score 0):

Although your regex seems working, try using this one:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

It is a regex for e-mail matching used by HTML5. Now, if You want to require ending `.something`, then replace `*` with `+`. Still, e-mails in general do not require Your limitations so maybe You should stick to [the standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)?

Comment: I meant: replace `*` at the end of the expression with a `+`, not all of them :)

Comment: @Wojtek_Mazurek I did but not fixed. Perhaps its not the problem with regex but the syntax of HTML or CSS or JS may be

Comment: @LifeSaver I tried to troubleshoot the code from codepen today but it seems You changed it and it works now. Also, the code You've put in the question works too.

Comment: I was just checking the new suggested code and forget to write previous code. Now I used the same previous code that was at very first time. Please check and advise

Comment: I still don't undestand - the code at codepen works perfectly fine - only the `.something` adress is considered valid and lights up green. Maybe You mean that the onchange function doesn't fire off when typing? If so, then You can't just use setCustomValidity out of context - it is a method and needs to be used on an object.

Comment: @Wotek Mazurek when we pass only `something@something` even without `.` part its considering valid

Comment: I am using Firefox 114.0 on Nobara Linux 37. When I type `something@something` the script does nothing. When I press "Login" I get red border with a message: "Email format is not correct or is not in English Language" below. Could You try this on FF as I did?